# react native hooks can only be called inside body of a function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

i am new to react i need help with the usestate  need it to change style to display none saving
the text in state then show use it in the inline css the code is below

```
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Image} from "react-native";
import MashButton from "./src/CustomButton";
import Mashcalculator from "./src/calculator";
import { Textfit } from "react-textfit";
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";


const runstartfunc = (res) =>{
  if (res == 'Connected'){
      createTwoButtonAlert('continue');
  }else{
      createTwoButtonAlert('text');
  }
}


const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
     if(state.isConnected == true){
        runstartfunc('Connected');
     }else{
        runstartfunc('Not Connected');
     }
});


const App = () => (  
  const [hidelogo, setHide] = useState("display:none;");

  useEffect(() => { 
  // Update the document title using the browser API
  unsubscribe();
}),

  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Image id="logo" style={styles.tinyLogo} source={require("./assets/logo.png")} />
     <Text id="logo-text" style={[styles.logotext, {hidelogo}]}>Show Bookie</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#2e0739",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  logotext: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#12cfed',
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "#20232a",
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#61dafb",
    color: "#20232a",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 15,
 }
 });

export default App;
```

When Ever i run the above code i get this error

**ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function** **component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:**
**1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)**
**2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks**
**3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app**

i don't know what could be wrong i will really appreciate if you guys can help me figure this out

Comment: Put the `useState("display:none;");` inside the App component. It should not be outside of a component. The error does explain this.

Comment: You've now changed the code. Does the error still occur?

Comment: thanks for the reply it shows unexpected token

Comment: that's a different error. does the original error still occur?

Comment: no it does not only the syntax error

Comment: then please close/delete this question. the edit has now completely changed it

Comment: i don't think that s advisable thanks for your concern anyways, Really need this to be fixed

Comment: No, you've changed the question and now accepted an answer. Please create another rather than changing questions completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Image} from "react-native";
import MashButton from "./src/CustomButton";
import Mashcalculator from "./src/calculator";
import { Textfit } from "react-textfit";
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";


const runstartfunc = (res) =>{
  if (res == 'Connected'){
      createTwoButtonAlert('continue');
  }else{
      createTwoButtonAlert('text');
  }
}


const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
     if(state.isConnected == true){
        runstartfunc('Connected');
     }else{
        runstartfunc('Not Connected');
     }
});


const App = () => {

const [hidelogo, setHide] = useState("display:none;");

  useEffect(() => { 
  // Update the document title using the browser API
  unsubscribe();
})
   return( <View style={styles.container}>
     <Image id="logo" style={styles.tinyLogo} source={require("./assets/logo.png")} />
     <Text id="logo-text" style={[styles.logotext, {hidelogo}]}>Show Bookie</Text>
  </View>
)
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#2e0739",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  logotext: {
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#12cfed',
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "#20232a",
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#61dafb",
    color: "#20232a",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 15,
 }
 });

export default App;
```

Comment: The edit makes this answer invalid now.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it shows **SYNTAX ERROR: Unexpected Token**

Comment: @YusufObafemi create a new question

Comment: thanks just copied your code to my app.js it works never knew you edited other stuff thanks a lot had sleepless night just because of this

Comment: Thank you too... But you should check the code before, not just copy past (code are like script, some can be malicious if coming from unverified sources)